# How to create Trackbars which do not call any function? OpenCV 3.1 with Python 2.7

Tags: python, opencv, trackbar, opencv3.1

I'm trying to threshold an image. I have used the `cv2.createTrackbar` function as-
 `cv2.createTrackbar('High H','image',0,179, None)`.
Now the last part is what I'm having trouble with. Further in my code, I use `highH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('High H','image')` to get my trackbar value and use it in the `cv2.inRange` function. So it becomes pretty obvious that I do not need to call a function as the last argument of the function. Now the problem is I can't seem to type in the function. I tried removing the last part, I got an error-

> cv2.createTrackbar only works with 5 arguements. Only 4 given.

Hmm, okay  seems like I can't skip a part.
Next I tried callback and nothing. I got this error:-

> When used nothing:- NameError: name 'nothing' is not defined
>   When used callback:- NameError: name 'callback' is not defined

Okay after a while I tried using None. Got this error:-

> TypeError: on_change must be callable

So how do I use the `cv2.createTrackbar` function without calling a function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create a simple function as expected?

Simple solution is to define a trivial function that returns the trackbar position. It will be called as the trackbar is moved by the user, but nothing will happen.

```
import cv2
def f(x): return x
win = cv2.namedWindow("MyImage")
tb = cv2.createTrackbar("MyTrackbar","MyImage",0,179,f)
#assume you have some cv2 image already loaded
cv2.imshow("MyImage", img)
```

You can also use an anonymous lambda function for the callback, which looks like the following:

```
import cv2
win = cv2.namedWindow("MyImage")
tb = cv2.createTrackbar("MyTrackbar","MyImage",0,179,lambda x:x)
#assume you have some cv2 image already loaded
cv2.imshow("MyImage", img)
```

Comment: As an aside, you could just use `def f(x): return`. There's no need to have a return value as it won't be used anywhere in this case.

Comment: you mean to create an empty function which doesn't do anything but is called  when the trackbar position is moved? And if I make any function, do I have to make the main function too then? Because my entire program isn't in a function

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

```
def f():
    pass
cv2.createTrackbar('thing', 'other thing', 0, 179, f)
```

This also works.